# Optimization, function

Tags: arrays

I've a problem

I would like to write:

max f(x)

sub {

Near to sub, I've to put the restriction functions. I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have needed to use `optidef` package: here there is a short example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{maxi*}<s>
{\scriptstyle a,b}{a+b+c}{}{}
\addConstraint{g }{=0 ,}{\quad lmno }
\addConstraint{p}{=0 ,}{\quad math }
\end{maxi*}
\end{document}
```

[image]